# Converting XYZ format to stl format

Tags: 3d, format-conversion

I am working for a project that creates XYZ format in my solid part. How could i convert from this format to stereolithography (STL) format with C# or c++? Is there any library for this work?

Comment: your question is very unclear, at least for me, what do you want to achieve? what do you mean by STL "format" ?

Comment: @GamErix: Given the "3D" tag, that's presumably [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_(file_format)) format.

Comment: stl format is kind of 3d design format

Comment: So "stl format" in this case has nothing to do with the C++ Standard Library components often referred to as the "STL?"

Comment: then I can suggest to remove the "C++" tag to avoid confusion or explicitly state that it's not about the C++ "STL"

Comment: @GamErix: Done. (Removing "C++" would be a bad idea in a question about C++).

Answer (score 2):

if your "XYZ" format has different ordering for the normals and vertexes rearrange them to the STL format in another variable and save that.

Note that if you save in binary format, then in C++ you can use the fstream library, it's also really helpful in that case to overload the << and >> operators so you can write to and read from the binary file "the C++ way".

The STL format (like in the comments) has a [certain way to be built up](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_(file_format)#Binary_STL);

```
UINT8[80] – Header
UINT32 – Number of triangles

foreach triangle
REAL32[3] – Normal vector
REAL32[3] – Vertex 1
REAL32[3] – Vertex 2
REAL32[3] – Vertex 3
UINT16 – Attribute byte count
end
```

you can wrap this in a class (note that `REAL32` equals to `float`) and use the fstream and overloaded << and >> operators to retrieve and store the binary format.

If you need an example for overloading the operators please look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16682032/1182183)